# Windows 8 App Store Updates not working

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

I have recently upgraded a computer from Windows 7 to Windows 8 using the upgrade assistant (keeping my apps and settings). It shows that 15 apps have updates in the store, but when I try to install them, the download progress never gets past 0% (they just sit there saying downloading). The same happens when I try to install a new application, it goes to downloading and never gets there. I have internet access, so that is not the problem.

Things I have tried so far after following every search result I could find on the topic:

- turned my account into a local account and back into a Microsoft account
- installed all windows updates
- ran wsreset.exe a few times
- rebooted several times

There are also a few other accounts on the computer (children's accounts), and they have the same issue - can't download new apps or update existing ones.

Any suggestions of what else I can try to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you checked event viewer? Anything strange there?

Answer (score 2):

I'll provide an update. Suddenly, without me doing anything in particular (apart from asking this question on SuperUser!), about 10 of the apps started downloading, and installed quickly. I then tried installing some more and they hung waiting to download for an age, but eventually after an hour or so, got going and installed themselves.

So I don't know whether there is something wrong with my PC, or maybe the Windows Store is perhaps not coping with demand very well at the moment.

Comment: I'm voting for this as a possibility. When I was using the Consumer Preview I noticed similar behaviour, which went away by itself.